# Only partial image showing as my background image. How can I use CSS to get the full image as my background?

Tags: css, image

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to figure out how to put a background image on my site. I've linked the image but it seems that it is only showing about 30% of the image. (Just the top of the photo is showing, the whole way across but none of the bottom) I'd like the entire image to be the background. The image is 594kb.

Here is my CSS:

```
 #nav1 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none; }

 #nav1 li {
  float: left; }

 #nav1 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }

 #nav1 li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }

 #nav1 li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff; }

.nav
{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(../images/image.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.jumbotron {
    padding:0px;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lobster', serif;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 { 
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 4em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 95px;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remember here, that for background images, each person has different screen resolutions and sizes. So having the entire image without some cropping or messing the image ratio is kind of impossible across different screen sizes.

Here is my preferred simple method using background-size cover. - I learned this from CSS Tricks..

```
html { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```